# How to Configure Notepad++ for fixed width tab indent

Tags: notepad++, tab-key

NotePad++ is displaying various length tab indentation. Please suggest how to configure to display the tab charater same as notepad.

Tab difference between NotePad and NotePad++

[image: Tab difference between NotePad and NotePad++]

Comment: I don't get it. Notepad is displaying various length tab indentation as well.

Comment: Oh, I think I figured out what you meant. Search for "elastic tabstops for notepad++". There are several plugins that may do what you want.

Comment: Hi @cesarse ,I've installed the Elastic Tabstops plugin. It doesn't help. Pls check the attached screenshot. The same text file appers diffently in Np and Np++. Tab appears as equally spaced in notepad but not in Np++. The orange arrow indicates the same [Tab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key) in different [length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998133/tab-space-inconsistency-in-a-txt-file-using-php) in space. I prefer to congiure Np++ to display text the same way Np does.

Comment: Now I see your point. Unfortunately, I never heard about such implementation for tabs. Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_stop to see how a tab is interpreted by editors. 
Oh! Please note that notepad does *not* use equally spaced tabs as well.

Comment: The only difference I see is that notepad has tag-length equal to 8 spaces and Notepad++ 4 spaces.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this behaviour is not reproductible.

Comment: also remember to click the checkmark if an answer helps you. Take the 1-minute [tour] to know how this site works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NotePad++ is displaying various length tab indentation

That's completely wrong. Tabs in most code editors stop at fixed intervals equal to **4 spaces** by default. You can clearly see it in your case where the distance gradually reduced until you have 4 characters, and the length is always 4 spaces. You can type more texts in the below line to see how they align

Plain text editors like Notepad OTOH typically uses **8-space** tab by default, similar to many terminals. You'll also see the same effect as above until you have full 8 characters. To make tab size 8 in Notepad++ just go to *Settings > Preferences > Language* and change the tab size for the corresponding language (*Normal Text* for plain texts like yours). Many other languages' conventions may have different tab sizes, for example most languages usually prefer 4-character tabs but xml, html, Pascal/Delphi... may prefer 2-character tabs

[image: Notepad++ tab settings]

But **you shouldn't use tabs at all**. The fact that tab has different interpretations in different environments makes it prohibited or discouraged in modern languages/coding conventions. For example in [Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces)

> Spaces are the preferred indentation method.
>
> Tabs should be used solely to remain consistent with code that is already indented with tabs.

So the better solution is to **check *"Replace by space"*** in Notepad++ as can be seen in the same preferences dialog above

If you want to convert the old files to space to make it consistent then select the whole text and **select *Edit > Blank Operations > TAB to Space***

[image: Notepad++ TAB to Space]

See

- [Never use hard tabs](https://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/13/never-use-hard-tabs/)
- [Notepad++ tabs are made of 4 space](https://superuser.com/q/1645668/241386)